# Splitting and joining back large tables in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

I need to break down a very large partitioned database saved in disk into parts, save the parts, sort each part, and then **join them back** to result in a sorted database. Loosely speaking, I want to apply merge sort to a very large partitioned. What should be the method of doing this? I can't load the entire table, because it is too large to work with.

For example,
Table size is 15 GB,
Memory is 50 GB,
Columns(data type) are data(p), id(i), value_a(C), value_b(j), value_c(f),

I want to sort the table by id. But I can't load the table because it is too large for the memory.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Schemas, sizes, RAM available, a simple example - all would help get answers ;)

Comment: Thanks for response;
RAM available is 50gigs. Table size is 15gigs. Let us say we have 5 columns, date, id, value a, value b and value c. And I want to apply sort on id.

Comment: and is this a date-splay or column splay?

Comment: this is a date splay

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can achieve this, based on my understanding from your response comments. Below is one solution, I'll assume you can rework it to best suit you. You say you want to "split by id" - I'm not sure what that means but below is a similar split by sym column (which would be there in your date splay) - switch column names etc as required.

**Assumptions**

- Database directory = `/data/db`
- New database directory = `/data/db2` -- of course that can be the same database directory as the original if you want, so long as the new table(s) is are not called by the same name as the source table
- Database port = `5001`
- Database host = `localhost`
- Big table = `table`
- `table` is a date splay from a tick database, so columns are date, sym, time
- You have some even distribution of sym values that can split the data into more manageable segments

  - Say `sym like "A*"` and `sym like "B*"` evenly distributes your `table` into a 50/50 split.

**A solution**

You have to be on the same host as the database. Open a q prompt:

```
/ open a connection to the db
h:hopen`::5001
/ pull down 1 partition's worth of data - a day for a date splay
/ conveniently this will take the value of enumerated syms too
table1:`time`sym xcols delete date from h"select from table where date=2014.01.01, sym like \"A*\""
table2:`time`sym xcols delete date from h"select from table where date=2014.01.01, sym like \"B*\""
/ note above we should use :: instead of : if you do all of this inside a function - to make the tables global values, as required by .Q.dpft
/ Write to location. Will sort by time and partition sym automatically
.Q.dpft[`:/data/db2;2014.01.01;`sym;] each `table1`table2
```

Once you've done this for all partitions you can delete `table` using your file system command (i.e. in unix, `rm`)

If your table is date splayed but doesn't have the sym/time columns as per normal tick databases, you can still do this by using functional `,`

```
@[`:/data/db2/2014.01.01/table2/;,;table2]
```

However you will also need to enumerate syms if you're enumerating, and set `#p` on columns that need it.

Alot of this is covered in the Kdb+ tutorial, highly recommend you read:

http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/contents

Comment: Thanks user2393012, this is not the exact solution I required, but I took elements of this and this has a worked for me.

Comment: instead of running queries, I grouped by a column, took out their indices and extracted column indices to make new tables. Please understand that the initial issue was that these tables are too large to be loaded in a service. I was not able to run the select queries you have written down because of memory allocation error.

Comment: I want to upvote the answer but I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: But this leaves the tables as two entities. I intend to have them integrated back with the attribute intact. Can you assist with that?

Comment: You can append the table as per the last code block in my answer but you'd have to ensure the resulting table's column (whichever you want to apply the attribute) is of the right form to apply the attribute (you can do this manually with the apply `@` and `#` operators)

Comment: When I append directly, the attribute gets lost(say table3:table1,table2). I had to extract the column from the table3,`p# it and put it back in the table3.

Comment: Yes the attribute can get lost... `#s` maintains if sort is maintained but `#p` disappears and has to be applied manually